# Bluetooth socket as a global variable android

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, global-variables

Is it possible to have the Bluetooth RFCOMM socket declared as a global variable, and used at all the activities of the application? or should I just keep on closing the socket and reopening it as I moving between activities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation. It would be safe to close the socket and reopen. As it is dangerous to pass a open socket around activities.